# How to change TextInputLayout material drop dow arrow drawable when using ExposeDropDownMenu style

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout, material-components, material-components-android

does anyone kn ow how to change `MaterialComponents` Spinner widget arrow image With `AutoCompleteTextView`.

code:

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
     android:id="@+id/contractSpinnerContainer"
     style="@style/TextInputLayout.FilledBox.Dense.ExposeDropDownMenu"
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_padding"
     app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineEnd"
     app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineStart"
     app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/registrationLastNameContainer">

  <AutoCompleteTextView
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:hint="Country"
         android:imeOptions="actionNext"
         android:includeFontPadding="false"
         android:inputType="textPersonName"
         android:maxLines="1"
         android:textColor="@color/ts_black"
         android:textSize="@dimen/login_input_text_size" />

 </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

result that want to change:

[image]

Comment: Tried with `app:endIconMode="custom"` and `app:endIconDrawable="@drawable/custom_icon"` ?

Comment: P.S. it is working without `app:endIconMode="custom"`

Comment: Maybe is too late, but you can do this: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67604501/1417235)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So with a help of @MatPag answer is:

```
app:endIconMode="custom"
app:endIconDrawable="@drawable/custom_icon"
```

and actually on `API29` it is working without `app:endIconMode="custom"`, haven't tested on other API's.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set background using theme changes of parent.

Comment: Changing  background is only working for Spinner widget, but here is TextInputLayout with ExposeDropDownMenu style

Comment: you need to create theme from extend parent theme "TextInputLayout.FilledBox.Dense.ExposeDropDownMenu" extend this parent theme and set your background in this.

Comment: No, it is not working this way. Answer is in comment under question

Comment: @AntonisRadz Okay, great